# How to make background service to track GPS location even if application is closed in xamarin.forms (android)?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

**I am working in xamarin.forms.** I want to create background service for Android. 
**My requirement is to track device location (Latitude, longitude, place name, Employee code) and inserted to the web server every after 5 min. After successful login, service has been started and for a particular employee, data is start inserting. Even if the app is closed still service should be running in background and data is keep inserting.**

My code is

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Locations;
using Android.Net;
using Android.OS;
using HRMS;
using HRMS.Interface;
using HRMS.TableAttributes;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Plugin.Geolocator;
using Plugin.Geolocator.Abstractions;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Threading;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using static HRMS.ServiceLayer.ServiceClasses;
using HRMS.MenuController;
using HRMS.Droid;
using Android.Provider;

namespace SilverHRMS.Droid.Service
{
    [Service]
    public class GPSTrackingService : Android.App.Service
    {
        #region Private Variables
        static readonly string TAG = "X:" + typeof(GPSTrackingService).Name;
        static int TimerWait = 300000; //150000;//25000 25 Sec; // 10 min 600000 and 20 Min 1200000
        Timer _timer;
        readonly string logTag = "GPSTrackingService";
        private string deviceId = "";
        private string googleAPI = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng={0},{1}&sensor=false";
        #endregion

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="intent"></param>
        /// <param name="flags"></param>
        /// <param name="startId"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
        {
            try
            {
                // Log.Debug(TAG, "OnStartCommand called at {2}, flags={0}, startid={1}", flags, startId, DateTime.UtcNow);
                //_timer = new Timer(o => { Log.Debug(TAG, "Hello from GPSTrackingService. {0}", DateTime.UtcNow); GetCurrentLocation(); }, null, 0, TimerWait);
                _timer = new Timer(o => { GetCurrentLocation(); }, null, 0, TimerWait);

                //_timer = new Timer(o => { GetCurrentLocation(); }, null, 0, TimerWait);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var fileService = DependencyService.Get<ISaveException>();
                fileService.SaveTextAsync(App.FileName, ex.StackTrace);

            }
            return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="intent"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
        {
            // This example isn't of a bound service, so we just return NULL.
            return null;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// On Destroy App
        /// </summary>
        public override void OnDestroy()
        {
            base.OnDestroy();

            _timer.Dispose();
            _timer = null;
            //Log.Debug(logTag, "Service has been terminated");
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get Current Location and Insert to DB
        /// </summary>
        public async void GetCurrentLocation()
        {

            try
            {
                string statusMessage = string.Empty;
                var locator = CrossGeolocator.Current;
                locator.DesiredAccuracy = 100;
                //Log.Debug(TAG, " getting GPS connection...");
                if (App.MyEmployeeId != null)
                {
                    #region Check Internet Connection
                    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)GetSystemService(ConnectivityService);
                    NetworkInfo activeConnection = connectivityManager.ActiveNetworkInfo;
                    bool isOnline = (activeConnection != null) && activeConnection.IsConnected;
                    #endregion

                    #region Check GPS Location Position and Emp Code
                    //LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)GetSystemService(LocationService);
                    bool isGPSOn = App.CheckGPSConnection();

                    Position position = null;
                    if (isGPSOn)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            position = await locator.GetPositionAsync(timeoutMilliseconds: 10000);
                        }
                        catch (Exception)
                        {
                            position = null;
                        }
                    }

                    #endregion

                    #region Insert Location to Local DB or Server DB

                    //Device Has Internet Connection 
                    if (isOnline)
                    {
                        #region Online Location Insert Direct to the Server Database
                        if (position != null)
                        {
                            List<GPSTrackingLocationClass> lcListOnline = new List<GPSTrackingLocationClass>();
                            GPSTrackingLocationClass objGPSTrack = new GPSTrackingLocationClass();
                            objGPSTrack.Latitude = position.Latitude;
                            objGPSTrack.Longitude = position.Longitude;
                            objGPSTrack.EmpCd = App.MyEmployeeId;
                            objGPSTrack.GPS_Track_DateTime = App.GetDateTime(DateTime.Now);

                            IDevice device = DependencyService.Get<IDevice>();
                            deviceId = device.GetIdentifier();
                            deviceId = deviceId.Replace("+", "%2B");
                            objGPSTrack.DeviceId = deviceId;

                            string url = string.Format(googleAPI, position.Latitude, position.Longitude);
                            try
                            {
                                XElement xml = XElement.Load(url);
                                if (xml.Element("status").Value == "OK")
                                {
                                    objGPSTrack.PlaceName = xml.Element("result").Element("formatted_address").Value;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    objGPSTrack.PlaceName = string.Empty;
                                }
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {

                            }

                            lcListOnline.Add(objGPSTrack);

                            if (lcListOnline.Count > 0)
                            {
                                string jsonContentsOnline = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(lcListOnline);
                                var responseOnline = await HRMS.ServiceLayer.GetResponseFromWebService.GetResponsePostData<HRMS.ServiceLayer.ServiceClasses.RootObject>(HRMS.ServiceLayer.ServiceURL.PostGPSLocation, jsonContentsOnline);
                                if (responseOnline.Flag == true)
                                {
                                    statusMessage = responseOnline.Message;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        #endregion

                        #region Local Database Entries Insert to Server Database
                        List<LocationTracking> lcListOffline = SideMenu.repoLocation.GetAllLocationAsync();
                        if (lcListOffline != null)
                        {
                            if (lcListOffline.Count > 0)
                            {
                                ObservableCollection<LocationTracking> lvCollection = new ObservableCollection<LocationTracking>(lcListOffline);

                                List<GPSTrackingLocationClass> lcListGoingtoOnline = new List<GPSTrackingLocationClass>();
                                foreach (var item in lvCollection)
                                {
                                    GPSTrackingLocationClass objGPSTrackOffline = new GPSTrackingLocationClass();
                                    objGPSTrackOffline.Latitude = item.Latitude;
                                    objGPSTrackOffline.Longitude = item.Longitude;
                                    objGPSTrackOffline.EmpCd = item.EmpCd;
                                    objGPSTrackOffline.GPS_Track_DateTime = item.GPS_Track_DateTime;
                                    objGPSTrackOffline.DeviceId = item.DeviceID;

                                    string urlAPI = string.Format(googleAPI, item.Latitude, item.Longitude);

                                    try
                                    {
                                        XElement xmlURL = XElement.Load(urlAPI);
                                        if (xmlURL.Element("status").Value == "OK")
                                        {
                                            objGPSTrackOffline.PlaceName = xmlURL.Element("result").Element("formatted_address").Value;
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            objGPSTrackOffline.PlaceName = string.Empty;
                                        }
                                    }
                                    catch (Exception exe)
                                    {

                                    }

                                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(objGPSTrackOffline.PlaceName))
                                    {
                                        lcListGoingtoOnline.Add(objGPSTrackOffline);
                                    }
                                }

                                if (lcListGoingtoOnline.Count == lvCollection.Count)
                                {
                                    string jsonContentsOffline = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(lcListGoingtoOnline);
                                    var responseOffline = await HRMS.ServiceLayer.GetResponseFromWebService.GetResponsePostData<HRMS.ServiceLayer.ServiceClasses.RootObject>(HRMS.ServiceLayer.ServiceURL.PostGPSLocation, jsonContentsOffline);
                                    if (responseOffline.Flag == true)
                                    {
                                        statusMessage = responseOffline.Message;
                                        SideMenu.repoLocation.RemoveLocationAsync();
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        #endregion
                    }
                    //Device Has No Internet Connection 
                    else
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            if (position != null)
                            {
                                IDevice device = DependencyService.Get<IDevice>();
                                deviceId = device.GetIdentifier();
                                deviceId = deviceId.Replace("+", "%2B");
                                string newDate = App.GetDateTime(DateTime.Now);
                                SideMenu.repoLocation.AddNewLocationAsync(newDate, position.Latitude, position.Longitude, App.MyEmployeeId, deviceId, "--");
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            //Log.Debug(TAG, "Please turn on GPS in your headset");
                        }
                    }
                    #endregion
                }
            } 
            catch (Exception ex) 
            {
                var fileService = DependencyService.Get<ISaveException>();
                await fileService.SaveTextAsync(App.FileName, ex.StackTrace);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Start Location Service
        /// </summary>
        public static void StartLocationService()
        {
            // Starting a service like this is blocking, so we want to do it on a background thread
            //new Task(() =>
            //{
            // Start our main service
            try
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Android.App.Application.Context, typeof(GPSTrackingService));
                Android.App.Application.Context.StartService(intent);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var fileService = DependencyService.Get<ISaveException>();
                fileService.SaveTextAsync(App.FileName, ex.StackTrace);
            }
            //}).Start();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Start Location Service
        /// </summary>
        public static void StartApplication()
        {
            try
            {
                Intent start = new Intent(Android.App.Application.Context, typeof(MainActivity));
                // my activity name is MainActivity replace it with yours
                start.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
                Android.App.Application.Context.ApplicationContext.StartActivity(start);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var fileService = DependencyService.Get<ISaveException>();
                fileService.SaveTextAsync(App.FileName, ex.StackTrace);
            }
        }

        public static void SendEmail(string text)
        {
            var email = new Intent(Android.Content.Intent.ActionSend);
            email.PutExtra(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraEmail, new string[] { "pankit.patel@silvertouch.com" });
            email.PutExtra(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraSubject, "Send Crash Report");
            email.PutExtra(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraText, "Hello, " + text);
            email.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
            email.SetType("message/rfc822");
            Android.App.Application.Context.ApplicationContext.StartActivity(email);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Stop Location Service
        /// </summary>
        public static void StopLocationService()
        {

            // Check for nulls in case StartLocationService task has not yet completed.
            //Log.Debug("App", "StopGPSTrackingService");
            try
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Android.App.Application.Context, typeof(GPSTrackingService));
                Android.App.Application.Context.StopService(intent);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var fileService = DependencyService.Get<ISaveException>();
                fileService.SaveTextAsync(App.FileName, ex.StackTrace);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**This service is only running when app is open (even in background) but if I close the app then service is automatically stop working. How to solve this issue? I have so many xamarin blogs regarding this topic but I din't get any workaround yet**.

**How to make background service that should be running even after app is close?**

Comment: Make it a **foreground** service : https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/services/foreground-services/

Comment: I wouldn't run timer in service for location. You can setup the system to wake you up if location changes.

Comment: ok instead of timer I can use location Listener but the main important thing is that it has to be run even when the app is closed. (app is totally closed not running in background also)

Comment: Is service should be sticky?

Comment: Yes, sticky. If you make your service foreground you have to provide user notification in status bar, not sure if you want that. Location services usually run without making service foreground even if your app is killed. Some manufacturers will kill all services when your app is removed from recent list but most of them will not do that with location provider services. When you reply you should add @YuriS for me to get notification about new comment

Comment: @YuriS : As per above code my service is already 'sticky' but still it didn't work and correct your word Service should be running in background, not in foreground. I still facing the issue and not getting a proper answer.

Comment: have you tried to configure it for system calls instead of timer? I said foreground service, not running in foreground, that comment was related to previous comment of SushuHangover